# SQLAlchemy: filter by datetime in JSON field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to filter a query based on a date in an JSON DB field (postgres).

E. g. for integer comparison this syntax is working:

```
r = Customer.query.filter(Customer.jsondata[('basic', 'age')].astext.cast(Integer) > 18).all()
```

But how does this query work for a datetime in iso format that should be no older than 12 months:

```
r = Customer.query.filter(Customer.jsondata[('basic', 'dateCreated')].astext.cast(???) > comparison_value).all()
```

What do I need to cast?

What type can the comparison value be?

Is my idea the right concept at all?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do it in plain SQL first, and once you know it's working, *then* i*t's time figure out how to get that SQL using SQLAlchemy's features. But assuming you have the exact same query working with other types, then I'd try casting to `DateTime`...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ThiefMaster comment the solution was quite easy.

I used:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime
import pendulum

r = Customer.query.filter(
      Customer.custcontext_json[('basic', 'dateCreated')].astext.cast(DateTime) > pendulum.now('UTC').subtract(months= 12)
      ).all()
```